# jquery passing variable to function

Tags: jquery, css, variables, woocommerce

So I'm trying to implement this hover effect which works great however when the hover effect is over, I want to set a new background to a certain div. So far so good just that I need to somehow pass the variable value which I get when the user hovers the image to the ELSE function.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$('.yith_magnifier_thumbnail').hover(function() {
    ssrc = $(this).attr( "href" );
$('img.attachment-shop_single').attr("src", ssrc);

}, function(ssrc){
// HERE I NEED TO USE THE VARIABLE ssrc in order to set the background but all i get is an [object object] type 
        //var ssrc = $(this).attr( "href" );
console.log('url("' + $ssrc + '") !important'); 
   $('.yith_magnifier_zoom_magnifier').css("background-image", 'url("' + ssrc + '") !important');

});
```

Comment: plz create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `ssrc` is the event object, what's wrong with using `this.href` in both mouseenter and mouseleave handlers? You can also use jQuery `.data()` method for storing values and then retrieving them.

Comment: this.href returns undefined on mouseleave. can you please give me an example of how can I use .data()? as you can see I just started with jquery.